Access to internal nuget package from another Azure Devops feed
Background
We have two Projects at Azure Devops top level, TOOLS and APPLICATIONS.
The former is for general purpose code that should be reused. The latter is for the actual production applications.
Scenario
I have added a project to TOOLS called authorization.shared , it has been published as a nuget package and needs to be used by a solution from the APPLICATIONS feed.
The nuget has been published and can be referenced and used correctly.
The issue
After adding the reference to the nuget to my application, I get the following on the dotnet restore step of the application pipeline build:
error NU1101: Unable to find package authorization.shared. No packages exist with this id in source(s): 
C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, feed-0635e925-8deb-4329-92da-a82d57dc96d4, NuGetOrg [F:\a\1\s\MyApplication.API\MyApplication.API.csproj]

F:\a\1\s\MyApplication.API\MyApplication.API.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package authorization.shared. 
No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, feed-0635e925-8deb-4329-92da-a82d57dc96d4, NuGetOrg

Where 'feed-0635e925-8deb-4329-92da-a82d57dc96d4' is the feed hosting the nuget package.
My question
I don't have admin rights, so I can't change permissions myself. I have to request changes. I have looked into what I think needs to happen but as I can't try it for myself I want to be sure I ask the right change.
I think the following toggles need to be turned OFF, is that correct?

If not, or partially, what else needs to happen to allow access to my nuget package from another feed?
(You can find that under Project settings / Settings )
Update
I have bypassed the issue for now by publishing to the same feed as the consuming code. That gets me further (deadline to meet) and it's also a reasonable action because I was told the two feeds will be merged at some point anyway. They were created separately but the original reason apparently has become obsolete.
I intend to revisit this when priority has passed because I want to understand the core issue and see if I can get it working the way I intended.

Have you selected your feed in "Use packages from this Azure Artifacts feed
" on the Restore-step?

@DanielStackenland Do you have a link?

Here is a link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/packages/nuget-restore?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

It's a good thing to specify that, but it still requires rights to execute. And apparently, likely because I currently don't have them, it causes dotnet restore to run forever (or at least for as long as I have patience) so I had to abort.

We had precisely this problem. I have admin permissions; I changed these settings, at the organisation level. No change; however upon inspection this action had only unlocked (note not disabled) the options at the project level. The project level still had these options active; however no longer were they locked with an alt-text of This setting cannot be changed as it is enforced at the organization level. I deactivated the options at the project level - everything now works.
So ultra-important note: change these settings twice, once at each administrative level. Tysm!


I think the following toggles need to be turned OFF, is that correct?

Yes. Since the feed and the Pipeline are in two projects, the option: Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines need to be disabled in the Project Settings -> Settings.

If this option is turned on, it will restrict the Pipeline to only access the resources of the current Project (e.g. feed, repo)
In addition, when the pipeline run dotnet steps, it will use the Build Service Account to access the feed.
You need to grant the Contributor role to the Build Service Account in Azure Artifacts -> Target Feed -> Settings -> Permissions.
Project level: Projectname Build Service(OrganizationName)
Organization level: Project Collection Build Service(OrganizationName)
For example:

For more detailed info, you can refer to these docs: Manage build service account permissions and Pipelines permissions and my other answer: DevOps Pipeline Can't Restore Using Artifact Feed

I've requested this change, we'll see.

@Spikee Feel free to let us know the result or share further questions.

On the other hand, After you perform the changes in answer, you can also add the NuGetAuthenticate task before the dotnet restore task to authenticate the feed.

@Spikee Is there any update about this ticket? If you disable the option: Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines. Will it work as expected?

Sadly no change after update.

@Spikee If possible, can you share your current Pipeline definition with us? And have you tried to grant the Contributor role to the build service account in feed settings?

I have bypassed the issue for now by publishing to the same feed as the consuming code. That gets me further (deadline to meet) and it's also a reasonable action because I was told the two feeds will be merged at some point anyway. They were created separately but the original reason apparently has become obsolete.

@Spikee If possible, you can add a new answer and share the result. Then you can accept it. This will be helpful to other users who has the same issue.

I will add it as an update to my question, I want to revisit the original issue when the priority has passed, so I understand the core issue and maybe rectify it so things work the way I want it.

No problem. Feel free to let me know if you need any help from my side in the future.

If it helps anyone else: additionally collection-level Build service (or each project level build service) permissions are also required on the feed and the feed's default view, along with a NuGet Authenticate task before the restore.
