Error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source
Background
I am troubleshooting the build pipeline of a greenfield project. Everything worked correctly before, recently I added a nuget package that comes from the same internal Artifacts Feed. To be sure all nuget sources are found [or that's the hope] I am using a nuget.config file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="my-feed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-feed/_packaging/my-feed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>

It is used for dotnet restore like this:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      feedsToUse: 'config'
      nugetConfigPath: './nuget.config'
      verbosityRestore: 'Normal'

That works without a glitch.
The issue I am running into
The next step is to run my unit tests, it has been set up like this (I haven't touched it):
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*.tests*/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"'
    publishTestResults: true

When running the logs display the following:
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj --logger trx --results-directory D:\a\_temp --configuration Release "--collect:XPlat Code Coverage"
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Domain\MyProject.Domain.csproj (in 80 ms).
D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Contracts\MyProject.Contracts.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-feed-mes/_packaging/my-feed-mes/nuget/v3/index.json. [D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj]
D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-feed-mes/_packaging/my-feed-mes/nuget/v3/index.json.
  Failed to restore D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Contracts\MyProject.Contracts.csproj (in 7.73 sec).
  Failed to restore D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj (in 7.83 sec).
D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-feed/_packaging/my-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-feed/_packaging/my-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
D:\a\1\s\MyProject.Tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-feed/_packaging/my-feed/nuget/v3/index.json.

Ultimately it keeps running and I have to cancel it (or I guess it would stop at some time but I can't wait that long).
My question

What may cause this error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for
source error and how do I solve it?

Other than adding an internal nuget package (and using nuget.config to be certain the sources are correct on the server) nothing was changed.

Based on your description, the dotnet restore step can restore the packages successfully, but the dotnet test step will show the NU1301 error.
The cause of the issue is that dotnet restore step will have cleaned up the credentials it used. Then  the valid credentials cannot be read in the dotnet test step.
Refer to this doc: Why is my build, publish, or test step failing to restore packages?

Most dotnet commands, including build, publish, and test include an implicit restore step. This will fail against authenticated feeds, even if you ran a successful dotnet restore in an earlier step, because the earlier step will have cleaned up the credentials it used.

Since you have added the dotnet restore step in the Pipeline, you can add the argument: --no-restore in the dotnet test step to skip implicit restore step.
For example:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*.tests*/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"'
    publishTestResults: true

On the other hand, since the separate dotnet restore step works fine, we can confirm that other feed-related settings in the project are correct.

Your suggestion of --no-restore indirectly brought me to a working solution. Adding it made the process complain about not finding restored packages, but I already had done a dotnet restore so I merged the build and test stages together. That worked. Then I got an error on the packaging stage, so I merged that together as well. Works fine now!

Adding --no-restore to the test task also sped it up a LOT (not surprisingly), so an added bonus.

@Spikee Glad to know that it can work for you now!!

@Spikee I have one more question. Just want to know if the issue in this ticket is also solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78314517/access-to-internal-nuget-package-from-another-azure-devops-feed if you still have issue, I really want to help you solve it too.

I have by-passed it for now, I  will answer there.
